# Docker Swarm Worker Error: Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have been following [this tutorial](http://tutorial) for setting up a multihost network on Hyperledger Fabric, but while joining PC2 as worker for the docker swarm, I am getting an error.

I have executed the following steps.

On PC1,

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (632ijg7z6mktr0w9quilvn1i2) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5qmka8a239apira1zmnk76lrnfdrxnb6dj8cjgrj6x2hfqmxin-anau7v6yg89lauoxsvkwp7qwm 192.168.43.78:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

Followed by creating the manager, i.e., PC1

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm join-token manager
To add a manager to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5qmka8a239apira1zmnk76lrnfdrxnb6dj8cjgrj6x2hfqmxin-5jkpf59ns743nvco9y7t66ncb 192.168.43.78:2377

himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5qmka8a239apira1zmnk76lrnfdrxnb6dj8cjgrj6x2hfqmxin-5jkpf59ns743nvco9y7t66ncb 192.168.43.78:2377
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm leave
Error response from daemon: You are attempting to leave the swarm on a node that is participating as a manager. Removing the last manager erases all current state of the swarm. Use `--force` to ignore this message.
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm leave --force
Node left the swarm.
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5qmka8a239apira1zmnk76lrnfdrxnb6dj8cjgrj6x2hfqmxin-5jkpf59ns743nvco9y7t66ncb 192.168.43.78:2377
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

These are the ifconfig settings of PC1

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~$ ifconfig
br-265f83fad915 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:a3:89:fa  
          inet addr:172.22.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-550f9551727c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:e8:e6:a4:97  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-76955e67b3d1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8e:58:c5:c0  
          inet addr:172.21.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-966ad10fdc06 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:a2:f4:bc:a5  
          inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:a2ff:fef4:bca5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21754 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:18096 (18.0 KB)  TX bytes:935049 (935.0 KB)

br-e6ebf3138263 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:56:09:e4:e3  
          inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f9:bd:e0:ba  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:f9ff:febd:e0ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2849 (2.8 KB)

docker_gwbridge Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fd:7c:f5:19  
          inet addr:172.23.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:fdff:fe7c:f519/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9970 (9.9 KB)

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:8c:fd:75:f5:c6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:154580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:154580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14853461 (14.8 MB)  TX bytes:14853461 (14.8 MB)

wlp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:14:01:8d:a8:fd  
          inet addr:192.168.43.78  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e12:3ebd:1415:dfc9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4332918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3582621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1241011858 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:585873205 (585.8 MB)
```

Not sure if the correct IP address is used in the commands. The port, however, is correct.

[image]

Comment: Your tutorial link doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `init` Swarm, that first node is already in the Swarm as the first master. After you get the join command for future nodes, you'll need to connect (ssh, etc.) to those nodes and then install docker before running the `docker swarm join` command on those nodes.